# Register RowCommand via Jquery Asp.net Webforms

Tags: asp.net

I have created a gridview that loads more data on mouse scroll down. My issue is that this gridview has RowCommand event, so this means every time i append new rows, i need to also register RowCommand event via Jquery. How can i achieve this ? Please see my code below :

```
var OpenUserNo = 1 ;

for (var i = 0; i < dataValues.length; i++) {
     $('#<%=gv.ClientID%> tr:last').after("<tr><td>" + dataValues[i].TotalComplaints +
                    "</td><td><a class='grid-hyperlink-green' href='javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphBody$gv', 'OpenUser$" + OpenUserNo +"')'>Details</a></td></tr>");

     OpenUserNo++;
}
```

Comment: You'll have to consider that all rows added via jquery will be lost after `postback`. I tested it and even they were lost after `partial postback`. Are `ScriptManager` and `UpdatePanel` from `Ajax Control Toolkit` an option for you?

Comment: It's better explained at these refferences:  https://forums.asp.net/t/1928283.aspx?add+row+to+gridview+using+jquery `space space space`  https://forums.asp.net/t/1885839.aspx?Add+rows+to+gridview+using+jquery

Comment: Yes, post back is my number one challenge. I will try Ajax Control Toolkit. Thank you.